# How to display view.php through link in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a two models register and skill,on Registers view page i added a link

```
echo CHtml::link('skill details',
                       Yii::app()->createUrl('skill/view',array(
                                                         'skill_id'=>1
                                                         )));
```

When clicking on that shows, I get an error "Your request is invalid".i change the access permission of view page to "*".How can i make this Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
echo CHtml::link('skill details',
    Yii::app()->createUrl('skill/view',array(
        'id'=>1
)));
```